# Nintendo Wii U GameCube Controller Adapter on Nintendo Wii

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, nintendo-gamecube

so I'm realizing my black Nintendo Wii doesn't have the gamecube ports on the top part. I thought the top was a lid and it looked like the top was supposed to come off when the front part of the top came off as bit and when I looked inside I saw ports. Problem was the rest of the flap looked screwed in.

So since I cant get to the ports I wanna order a GameCube port adapter. But when I search online for it they all say WiiU. Is this still compatible with the Nintendo Wii system?

Comment: Honestly, for what the adapter costs you could probably buy a used Wii with GameCube support if you look hard enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately it won't work with the Wii. It barely works with the Wii U. The adapter won't work with Wii games that support GameCube controllers whether played on a Wii U or a Wii. Games have to be specifically designed to use it and Super Smash Bros. For Wii U is the only game it works with it at the moment.

You'll have to get an older Wii with GameCube ports if you want to play Wii games (or GameCube games) using the GameCube controller.

Nitendo's [FAQ on the GameCube Controller Adapter](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13277/~/gamecube-controller-adapter-%26-gamecube-super-smash-bros.-edition-controller-faq) spells out all these limitations.